# Trying to create a "List of Values " including a table value and numbers below it

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, lov

So basically say I have a table called "Device" and then one of the columns is "Quantity," what if I wanted to create a list of values that takes that number, say the quantity is 4, and the values are (quantity - 1) until !> 0, so in this case (4, 3, 2, 1)

I am using Oracle APEX and am assuming I need a dynamic LOV based on a sql query, but not sure how to get this. I've never used a for loop with PL/SQL

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to base this quantity on? How do you determine which 4 are chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Make sure that where I've put `/* xxx */` you include a where clause that comes up with only 1 record. Most likely, you will use the ID of the Device table here.

```
SELECT     ROWNUM display_value
,          ROWNUM return_value
FROM       DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (SELECT Quantity FROM Device WHERE /* xxx */)
ORDER BY   ROWNUM DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Just note you will need to do 'SELECT ROWNUM D, ROWNUM F' where D and F can be anything but you need to have two columns (first is display_value, second is return_value).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need loops for this.

```
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 4
order by level desc;
```

Comment: I was just using 4 as an example, but I need to be able to write something that will work for any value so basically for each row in this form I need to be able to choose how many I want depending on its specific value, which can change, so I need something that is not static. So in my case, I have a a table "Device", one of the columns is "Quantity," so I need something like      select quantity from device and from that "values subtracted by 1 until you hit 0"

Comment: I was just using 4 as an example too. Parametrize the query if you need to.